# How to copy to cells from a range if the columns to the right match?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I looked for a solution for this using VLOOKUP and programmatically and I couldn't find it. I hope you guys can help.

I have two spreadsheets with same headers and similar data. One is complete the other is not. The first column (lets call it "ID") of the completed spreadsheet messed up.

I want to copy the values from the "ID" column of the incomplete version to the new version based on if the cell to the right of each (lets call it "Names") matches.

To clarify, the algorithm or formula has to look through the column "Names" of the OLD (incomplete) version and if it finds a match in the NEW version, copy it to its left.

I cannot just sort alphabetically and copy and paste, because the completed worksheet has some duplicates that may be needed.

```
EDIT: EXAMPLE OF MY DATA:
Sheet1                                    Sheet 2
ID      NAME                     ID           Name        Age       
112     John                   156           Dog         11
113     Bob                    1xx           Bob         15    
156     Dog                    1xx           Bob         16 
                               1xx           John        18
```

Since the ID is messed up (because the ID I work with got messed up when exporting from Google Fusion Tables) I need to copy to the NEW file the "Ids" from the OLD version. This is just a simple example, I have over 200 000 rows of data.

Comment: give us a screenshot of your data organization plz. and your own attempt in solving it;

Comment: [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Can't screenshot my data, because is work stuff. However, I edited my question to give an example of what I'm trying to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `ID` is in A1 on both sheets and that the `xx` indicate IDs to be replaced, please add a new ColumnA in Sheet 2 and in A2 there:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(B2),B2,INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MATCH(C2,Sheet1!B:B,0)))
```

copied down to suit.

The first part `ISNUMBER(B2)` tests for a numeric ID in the data set that is a mixture of sound and corrupt. If that *is* a number *and* corrupt there may be no way to identify the corruption from the information provided.

So if that test is passed accept the value from the corrupted sheet (ie B2).

If however the test fails, then find the relevant `Name`'s location (for Row2 the relevant name is `Dog`) in the incomplete sheet (ie Row4) and use INDEX to lookup the value associated with `Dog` (to its left) in the incomplete sheet.

Comment: Thanks. Please would you mind explaining a bit what this formula does?

Comment: Great thank you! I think I was confused because of the part ..Match(C2, ...
Because I think it should be B2 instead. I changed it and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the new spreadsheet is called "New" and the old is called "Old,"  and assuming that the names appear in column A of each spreadsheet, starting in row 1, then use this formula in column B of the new spreadsheet:

=iferror(vlookup(New!A1,Old!$A:$A,1,false),"?????")

So your spreadsheet looks like this:

```
      A             B
1    Coke         =iferror(vlookup(New!A1,Old!$A:$A,1,false),"?????")
2    Pepsi        =iferror(vlookup(New!A2,Old!$A:$A,1,false),"?????")
3    Sprite       =iferror(vlookup(New!A3,Old!$A:$A,1,false),"?????")
4    asdfvasdl    =iferror(vlookup(New!A4,Old!$A:$A,1,false),"?????")
5    Dr. Pepper   =iferror(vlookup(New!A5,Old!$A:$A,1,false),"?????")
```

and it should display like this:

```
      A             B
1    Coke         Coke         
2    Pepsi        Pepsi        
3    Sprite       Sprite       
4    asdfvasdl    ???????
5    Dr. Pepper   Dr. Pepper
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't think that's applicable to what I'm trying to do though. I edited my question to include an example and be more specific about what I am trying to do. Thanks again!